# Using timestamp as column name in CQL

Tags: timestamp, cassandra, cql

I'm using CQL to create a column family with timestamp as my column name in cassandra. Has anyone tried it before? I have looked through timeuuid functions in CQL syntax. But I'm not sure as to how to use any of them in the CREATE or UPDATE queries to create a column name with timestamp in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `now()` function to generate a time UUID containing the current time.  For example:

```
create table timeuuid_test (key timeuuid primary key, value text);
insert into timeuuid_test (key, value) VALUES (now(), 'hello');
insert into timeuuid_test (key, value) VALUES (now(), 'hello2');
select * from timeuuid_test;

 key                                  | value
--------------------------------------+--------
 0ad77930-179b-11e3-8f29-19ac47defd2c |  hello
 0c305270-179b-11e3-8f29-19ac47defd2c | hello2
```